# If I use an XmlWriter then I can't choose where to write to, Serialize() requires a writer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlwriter

I am running into the problem where I can't write serialized objects to a specific location in an XML document.

If I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spellements>
<MapSave />
</Spellements>
```

And I want to load my list of objects into the MapSave tag. How do I do it?

(the List of object type Node is passed in)

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Node>));

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

string fileName = Application.dataPath + "/Saves/Save" + GameVariables.saveFile + ".xml";

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open), settings))
{
    ser.Serialize(writer, list);
}
```

I have no problem serializing all the objects and writing them to the file. It works fine, but I seem to have no way to write it specifically as elements inside the  area.

I have to use an XML writer to do Serialization, but there is no way to set the XML writer's "start writing here" location.  As of now it just overwrites the whole document.

(I've done more then my fair share of research, I know how to set the writing location when using an XmlDocument, but not with XmlWriter  -- Help please.

Comment: You need to read in the whole file, edit it using `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` then write it back out.

Comment: How do you edit an XmlDocument so that you can serialize AND add it to a specific node within the XmlDocument.  That is my original question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind everytime writing the whole file you can do something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Spellement
{
    public Spellement() { }

    List<Node> mapSave = new List<Node>();
    public List<Node> MapSave
    {
        get { return mapSave; }
        set { mapSave = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public Node() { }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Spellement));
using (XmlWriter st = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\test.xml"))
{
     xs.Serialize(st, s);
}
```

Comment: The problem would be that the document has much more information then just the MapSave node.  The XML file has more content, and its content is edited elsewhere as well, so I cannot re-write it every time.